# How do you filter by date "createdAt" with Algolia

Tags: swift, algolia

I need to sort my Alogolia database by the date the object is created. For some reason Algolia only displays the "createdAt" date wen creating an object. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of pointers:

- To sort results use: customRanking (check the Algolia documentation for more details).
- Algolia does not support DateTime attribute types so you need to convert your local DateTime into epoch.